# What is the benefit of "echo" chunks, while ouputing a file?

Tags: php, performance, file

What is benefit and difference between the following:

Statement 1:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header('Expires: ' . date('r',time() + 864000));
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
$splitString = str_split($contents, 1024);
foreach($splitString as $chunk)
echo $chunk;
```

Statement 2:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header('Expires: ' . date('r',time() + 864000));
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
echo $contents;
```

Comment: This is discussed here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425227/forced-downloading-large-file-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way TCP/IP packets are buffered, using `echo` to send large strings to the client may cause a severe performance hit. Sometimes it can add as much as an entire second to the processing time of the script. This even happens when output buffering is used.

If you need to echo a large string, break it into smaller chunks first and then echo each chunk. **So, using method 1 to split the string OR using `substr` to split it and sending to client performs faster for *large* files than method 2.**

Comment: pretty sure PHP/Apache are capable of handling this without help from PHP programmers...

Comment: @sbeam, I have personally tested it and found it better. Maybe some configurations of Web-server and PHP may do it automagically, but when you don't know which server is going to be used (IIS, Apache, Lighthttpd, etc), it's better to optimize your own script.

Comment: wow. any webserver out there is capable of handling the TCP packet construction without your help, these things are not written by idiots who don't know about TCP/IP (even IIS). Whatever benchmark you did was flawed somehow. This is a useless micro-optimization that doesn't even do anything except muddle the code.

Comment: @sbeam, I would advise you to please run a test yourself in some spare time and see the difference yourself.

Comment: @shamittomar this might make echo _seem_ faster, but it doesn't actually free resources. Solution is to tune your webserver http://fplanque.com/dev/linux/why-echo-is-slow-in-php-how-to-make-it-really-fast

Comment: @sbeam, yes I agree. BUT, what about all the **shared** webhostings where you can't change settings of your web-server ?

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1 adds unnecessary overhead and obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

in the first statement content divide into 1024 bytes chunks and one chunk have 1024 bytes content and in the second statement detemine the length of whole content ant then echo this but in first divide in chunk and then echo with help of for each one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$contents` is very large, you can echo it in chunks to stop the whole thing being echo'd at once.